# Integrate a standalone PHP page into Prestashop AND/OR modify rewrite rules

Tags: php, url-rewriting, prestashop

The requirement is to add a feature that sends an email to the shop's address through a form. This is for visitors that wish to find out if they're eligible for a 5 euro bonus.

I've done a standalone script that fills in this requirements and the form appears as it should when I enter the full url. However, clicking on a link to the same url from a product description produces a 404.

Could this be due to url rewriting? Can the PHP page co-exist with Prestashop or should I write a barebones module of some sort to fit in?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate" exactly? What does the script do?

Comment: Holy cow. Already three minus votes. I hope I've given sufficient detail.

Comment: @James, you haven't.  What do you mean by "Prestashop doesn't appear to accept direct links"?

Comment: @Brad: As an experiment I added a hyperlink in the description of a product. Entering shopurl.com/myscript.php shows the form. However, clicking on the link with the same url gives a 404. Any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I'm still trying to determine why a 404 is being displayed. To be honest, I'm having difficulty figuring out the rewrite rules as they're numerous.

Comment: I've switched to a simple html form. It'll do for now.

Comment: To answer the "answerable" part of your question, then yes -- you should write a module to implement such functionality rather than using a stand-alone script.

Comment: @Paul Campbell: Thank for confirming. Just for the sake of a writing exercise what parts of the questions would you change or omit?

Comment: I would think describing what you wanted to achieve (e.g. a form to check for eligibility for a discount) and then asking "What is the best method of implementing such a custom form in Prestashop?".

Comment: That's short and concise. I like that :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upvoted you after you revised the question to get you to -2. I hope this helps.

I am not familiar with Prestashop, but if it uses PHP which I believe it does because of your tags you can try a few things:

1 - you can add an event listener to the submit button. When the form submit button is pressed, the function will send an Ajax request to the server to send the email.

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    var foo = document.getElementById("bar");   
    foo.addEventListener("click", function_to_execute(), false);
}
```

The function_to_execute() will be called when the submit button is clicked.

You can add this code to the script where the form is, or if you don't want to hack Prestashop code you can prepend it to all scripts using php.ini. Just add:

```
auto_prepend_file = "/path/to/file/with/function.php"
```

I believe this might work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks jdias. I don't have access to the php.ini and still get a 404 while following a link to the script. However, I'll see if it's possible to add some javascript through the MCE editor.